# Interaction between package, use-package, and quelpa

Tags: package, use-package

I am testing `quelpa` with my `use-package` configuration. My question is: Is `quelpa` meant to complement `use-package`, or rather to replace it?

I have the following code in my init file:

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(setq
 package-enable-at-startup nil
 package-user-dir (concat user-emacs-directory "elpa")
 package-archives
 '(("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
   ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
   ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")
   ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
   )
 package-archive-exclude-alist
 '(("melpa" elnode)
   ("melpa" org-trello)
   ("melpa" org)
   ("marmalade" org)
   ("gnu" org)
   ("org" org))
 )


(if (require 'quelpa nil t)
    (quelpa-self-upgrade)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (url-insert-file-contents "https://raw.github.com/quelpa/quelpa/master/bootstrap.el")
    (eval-buffer)))
(setq quelpa-upgrade-p t)


(quelpa 'use-package)
(require 'use-package)

(package-initialize)
```

Comment: There's also a package called [`quse-package`](https://github.com/jaccarmac/quse-package) that merges the functionality of `quelpa` and `use-package` :)

Answer (score 9):

While `quelpa` and `use-package` have no direct relation with each other, there now is a package, [`quelpa-use-package`](https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa-use-package), which adds a `quelpa` handler to `use-package`. This allows one to use `use-package` with a  `quelpa` source package name or recipe, for example:

```
(use-package flycheck-pony
  :quelpa (flycheck-pony :fetcher github :repo "rmloveland/flycheck-pony"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`quelpa` is just a tool to build and install packages, `use-package` is another tool for configuring packages in a declarative manner.  They don't have anything to do with each other at all, therefore your question doesn't make much sense and can be answered with "No".

Source: I have commit access to `quelpa` and did contribute code to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the fact that you can answer it with a "no", proves that my question *does* make sense. The documentation of `quelpa` is so meagre that I couldn't understand exactly its purpose. Hence my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what's there not to understand about "Build and install your Emacs Lisp packages on-the-fly and directly from source.".

Comment: That's plain enough, alright. But nowhere does it state whether and how it interacts with `package` or `use-package`. In fact, I noticed that `quelpa` both upgrades the `melpa` directory, and creates another of its own. Nowhere---at least to my knowledge---does the `readme.md` explain such a proliferation of lisp files, and other related issues.

Comment: Asides from the fact that how it does the building is an implementation detail, the relation to package.el and MELPA is cleared up in the overview section that follows the introduction. "quelpa uses recipes in MELPA's format to build your desired packages from source and installs them using the built-in Emacs package manager.". package.el is said built-in package manager, the next sentences explain use cases, one of which is a "local MELPA" which is the `melpa` directory you've seen on disk. None of this knowledge is required to use it or to put it differently, it's an implementation detail.